# Mac Location Services: Frequent Polling?

Tags: macos, privacy, geolocation, maps

I frequently see the Location icon in my menu bar despite not having any apps running that use it. When I click it, it says Maps is using my location, even when I don't have the maps open at all. Is this normal? Should I be worried about some kind of security issue?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it is significant locations, which might need maps to name the coordinates.

> Significant Locations allows your Mac to identify places significant to you in order to provide useful location-related information in Maps, Calendar, Reminders and more. Significant Locations are encrypted and can’t be read by Apple. Click Details to view a list of locations that have been identified. You can select and remove locations from the list or click Clear History to remove all the locations.

- https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mh35873/mac
- https://osxdaily.com/2019/09/05/disable-clear-significant-locations-mac/